# Joining a thread from another function

Tags: c++, pthreads

I'm trying to create a thread that does work in a non-blocking fashion, and the caller has the option whether to wait for the thread or not.

```
class A {
public:
  void run();
  void wait();
  pthread_t worker;
};
```

The `run()` function creates a thread and returns immediately. If the user needs to wait, he can call `wait()`. The definitions look like

```
void A::Run () {
  //create worker thread
  pthread_attr_t attr;
  pthread_attr_init(&attr);
  pthread_attr_setdetachstate(&attr, PTHREAD_CREATE_JOINABLE);
  FATALIF(pthread_create(&worker, &attr, work, param), "Error creating worker thread.");
  pthread_attr_destroy(&attr);
}

void A::WaitUntilDone () {
  FATALIF(pthread_join (worker, NULL), "joining threads failed.");
}
```

When I call `WaitUntilDone()`, however, the caller is not blocked at all. Then I tried moving the `join` from `WaitUntilDone()` to `Run()`, it works:

```
void A::Run () {
  //create worker thread
  pthread_attr_t attr;
  pthread_attr_init(&attr);
  pthread_attr_setdetachstate(&attr, PTHREAD_CREATE_JOINABLE);
  FATALIF(pthread_create(&worker, &attr, work, param), "Error creating worker thread.");
  FATALIF(pthread_join (worker, NULL), "joining threads failed.");
  pthread_attr_destroy(&attr);
}

void A::WaitUntilDone () {
  // do not wait here
  // FATALIF(pthread_join (worker, NULL), "joining threads failed.");
}
```

In all examples of `pthread_join` I cound find, the `pthread_join` call comes immediately after `pthread_create`, so it seems to me that we cannot separate these functions. Is there any workaround?

Comment: you could use a static variable that indicates whether to wait or not. in any case u have to set this variable before run() because run executes n returns immediately as you said. make sure that the user sets this variable before he runs the thread..

Comment: In this api, the user has to call `wait` after `run`, but it seems that I can try defining a variable that's to be set in the end of the `work` function, and use a `while` loop to block `wait`..

Comment: Can you make a small, compilable code snippet that demonstrates the issue? Normally it shouldn't be a problem to separate the `create` and `join` calls - I've written plenty of code that does so at least. Also, what is the return value of `pthread_join` - and are you sure that your worker thread is still running when you call `WaitUntilDone`?

Comment: the problem is that since this is threads we are talking about the order of execution of the main thread and child is independent. you could do like a timeout in the run method. wait for a while to see if the user calls WaitUntilDone() and set the static variable. if timeout then end thread. else wait until user resumes the thread.

Comment: Yes, it seems that my thread exits before join

Comment: If your thread has already exited when you call join, then that's why join returns immediately. Try calling for instance sleep(3) in your worker function, and see if that causes your wait function to block for a few seconds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The newly created thread is probably returning before you call the function that does `pthread_join`. Therefore, it won't block at all, however, it works properly.